# Packer with AWS SSO Profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

I'm trying to use packer with the "profile" variable (without needing to supply static access keys) which I am configuring using the `aws configure sso` command - but when trying to run the packer command I get the error:

> Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
> For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors

in my packer variables.json I have `"aws_profile": "sandbox"` and in my environment.json I have

```
"builders": [
        {
            "type": "amazon-ebs",
            "profile": "{{user `aws_profile`}}"
```

Am I missing something or is it not possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

as per the [source](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/aws/credentials/shared_credentials_provider.go#L139-L151)

```golang
// profile returns the AWS shared credentials profile.  If empty will read
// environment variable "AWS_PROFILE". If that is not set profile will
// return "default".
func (p *SharedCredentialsProvider) profile() string {
    if p.Profile == "" {
        p.Profile = os.Getenv("AWS_PROFILE")
    }
    if p.Profile == "" {
        p.Profile = "default"
    }

    return p.Profile
}
```

similar issue [Use of AWS credentials profile ignored #7427](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/7427)

Quoting from the issue:

> I found out what my issue was: my build.json was configured to use a specific profile ("profile": "default"), and that takes precedence over AWS_PROFILE. Once I removed the line everything was fine.

If those are correct then it might be the variable name itself.

```json
{
  "variables": {
    "aws_profile": "{{env `AWS_PROFILE`}}"
  },
  "builders": [{
    "type": "amazon-ebs",
    "region": "eu-central-1",
    "profile": "{{ user `aws_profile`}}"
[...]
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. Using the `AWS CONFIGURE SSO` seems to have quite a different effect on the .aws\config file ... doesn't appear as the normal config with access keys etc:

```
[profile sandbox] 
sso_start_url = https://[redacted].awsapps.com/start# 
sso_region = eu-west-2 sso_account_id = [redacted] 
sso_role_name = [redacted] 
region = eu-west-2 
output = json
```

Answer (score 1):

I am running packer with SSO by using the tool [aws2-wrap](https://github.com/linaro-its/aws2-wrap) like this

```
aws2-wrap --profile sso-profile-name packer build .
```

As stated in the docs:

> This is a simple script to make it easier to use AWS Single Sign On credentials with tools that don't understand the sso entries in an AWS profile.